# TFS build definition freezes when connecting remote machines

Tags: tfs, build-definition

When connecting to a remote TFS 2010 installation via my Visual Studio 2010, Process tab of Build Definition freezes. Everything seems to be disabled. Is there any work-around?

**UPDATE 1:**

By freezing I mean:

I can navigate to all tabs: General, Trigger, Workspace, Build Defaults, Process and Retention Policy. Except for Process tab, they all are working as excpected. When I click Process tab, it is showed, but none of parameters are shown, and the tab itself is in gray. Actually nothing could be clicked. It is like that Visual Studio is waiting for something to be completed or loaded.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have explored that when I leave Visual Studio alone for a long time about 20 or 30 minutes, the Process tab goes normal. That means all parameters appears and can be edited. That seems downloading or getting something from server causes this very very long delay.

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly is disabled? "Everything" is too broad. Does the process tab hang for some period of time then VS works again, or it hangs too long that you'd have to kill it? Can you view/change other tabs of the build definition?

Comment: Does this build definition have any custom assemblies? You can check that by looking at the properties of the build controller associated with this definition. When the Process tab is opened, the custom assemblies are (down)loaded to populate the parameters, so it could cause some delay, especially if the network latency is high.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out exactly what rights you have on that server with regards to administrating builds.

http://intovsts.net/2009/09/03/more-fine-grained-permissions-in-tfs2010/ and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx

I think one of the main ones is "edit build definition"

If you don't have rights, then there won't be a workaround.

**UPDATE:**
The only things I can really think of at this point is to put a sql monitor on the TFS Database and possibly, watch the network traffic to see how the network interface is being used.

It's possible that something is wrong on the database server causing a huge amount of load.  The other possibility is that the network is badly configured and running at 1Mb instead of 100Mb+.

Beyond those, I'd say call MS Support and open a trouble ticket.  This is by no means normal and is likely indicative of some underlying hardware or installation issue.

Comment: I am admin of both TFS server and my client. I have also admin rights in TFS domain network.

Comment: @afsharm: Being an admin on your domain is a very different thing than having administrative rights in TFS.  TFS has it's way of managing and maintaining rights.

Answer (score 0):

Afsharm,

Happend with me too. This happened when i had the build defination open on one VS instance in edit mode and i opened it for editing on another pc. After a while it errored saying "TFS 20391: Locked for blah blah..." I had to close my visual studio instance on both the machines and restart, it worked there after. These are very occassional cases and very hard to replicate. I would suggest restarting your visual studio session and trying again.

PS - Worth checking if some one else have the process template open for edit as well?

HTH.

Cheers, Tarun